# Error while using For loop, user input in Python

Tags: python

I am not understanding how to use a for loop with user input. More specifically I want to create a for loop that asks for more user input if the condition is met.

For example, I was thinking of doing the following:

```
number = input("what is the value")
for number in numbers:
   number = input("what is the value")
   numbers = [1,2,3]
if number = numbers
   print (number)
```

The above is a generalized code, what I am aiming for is getting the input( what is the value) to loop.

If I do it the way shown above the question gets repeated twice in the beginning.

If I remove line 1 my variable is undefined. If I remove line 3 later down my code that depends on the number variable gets undefined.

Can someone show me a better way to approach this with a different example?

Comment: Hints: 1. `Print != print`, edited. 2. `if number = numbers` also isn't `if number == numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a `while` loop

```
 while True:
   num = raw_input("what is the value ")
   num = int(num)
   number = [1,2,3]
   if num in number:
       pass
   else:
       break
```

As you said if `num` is present in `number` then the loop will run, else it will exit

Comment: I am interested in for loops, could a example using for loops be given as well.

Comment: If you want to use a for loop then you will get to run the loop for a limited times only. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve a limited loop. Until the user gives a incorrect input that goes against a given set of criteria.

Comment: Your problem is a bit tricky because `for` loop can run only for **limited times**. So you need to decide how many **chances** you want to give the user to type the **correct answer**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple for-loop that runs 5 times and asks input from the user. If the number she enters matches with the loop variable it prints success message. Happy programming :)

```
for i in range(5): #Runs this loop 5 times
    number = input("what is the value ? :")
    if number == i:
        print "You are correct"
    else:
        print "The correct answer is ", i
```

Logs:

```
what is the value ? :1
The correct answer is  0
what is the value ? :1
You are correct
what is the value ? :2
You are correct
what is the value ? :1
The correct answer is  3
what is the value ? :1
The correct answer is  4
```

**Update** : If you like animals so much

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'macaw', 'dove']
for ani in animals:
    animal = raw_input("what is the value ? :")
    if animal == ani:
        print "You are correct"
    else:
        print "The correct answer is ", ani
```

Logs:

```
what is the value ? :dog
The correct answer is  cat
what is the value ? :cat
The correct answer is  dog
what is the value ? :macaw
You are correct
what is the value ? :test
The correct answer is  dove
```

Comment: Interesting. What if you have two variables that need to be defined in the loop. For example: for cat in animals and you want to keep asking the user for a animal.

Comment: Updated the answer... Is that matching with what you wanted mate ?

Comment: I understand that. I think my explanation of my question needs to be improved. Sorry, I am new to Python and programming in general. So, in the loop do we need to always define our variable before the for statement, like for animals in the loop statement we need to define animals in a list? What if the definition of the variable is what the user puts in.                   C= input(some question)                                                   For something in c: #again want to loop some question after some valid condition